# Nonetype error in Sending an email to a teacher in python with SMTP

Tags: python

I used the code below to try to send an email to my teacher with my email and password:

```
import cs50
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage

def main():
    message = EmailMessage()
    message.set_content("This email verifies run-check of ASSIGNMENT")
    message['Subject'] = 'Assignment from ME'
    message['From:'] = 'MY EMAIL'
    message['To:'] = 'TEACHER'S EMAIL'

    with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com') as smtp:
        smtp.login("MY EMAIL", "MY PASSWORD")
        smtp.send_message(message)

    sys.exit(0)

if(__name__ == "__main__"):
    main()
```

However, I got an error message saying "TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, NoneType found". Any idea what went wrong? It just took me 30 minutes of trying to get the login to work with Less Secure Apps...

Edit: No, the problem is not the third apostrophe in 'TEACHER'S EMAIL'. in the actual teacher's email there is not apostrophe yet I still get the TypeError problem.

Edit 2: Whole error code here:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/some folder idk/SMF29.py", line 48, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/ubuntu/some folder idk/SMF29.py", line 42, in main
    smtp.send_message(message)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/smtplib.py", line 940, in send_message
    from_addr = email.utils.getaddresses([from_addr])[0][1]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/email/utils.py", line 112, in getaddresses
    all = COMMASPACE.join(fieldvalues)
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, NoneType found
```

Edit 3: seeing that some people surrounded their emails with <>, I tried that, and got a different error:
`smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials l11sm1375218qkk.101 - gsmtp')`
Which is confusing, because not only have I taken all the google steps including the enable less secure apps and verify device things, but I am only logged into that one account. Any idea what the problem could be?

Edit 4: turns out that was a stupid idea and after getting rid of the <>s around the emails and the colons in front of From and To it worked. I had previously accidentally forgotten to remove one pair of <> around my email after removing the colons.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please always post the **whole error message** with **full traceback**.

Comment: Just did, see if that makes it any clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As can be seen from the error traceback, specifically this line:

```
from_addr = email.utils.getaddresses([from_addr])[0][1]
```

You are missing the `from_addr`. The key for the `From` address is `From`, not `From:` (with a colon). Change the following line

```
message['From:'] = 'MY EMAIL'
```

to

```
message['From'] = 'MY EMAIL'
```

While you are at it, do the same for the `To` address as well.

See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html) for an example.

Comment: nevermind, i forgot to get rid of the <>s around the emails. now it works, thank you